# How can I remove non-duplicate numbers from an array?

Tags: arrays, pseudocode

I am trying to solve a Question of my data structure course where the question is write a psuedo code to remove non-duplicate numbers from the array and print.

```
j<--0
m<--0
for i<--0 to i<k do
    for j<--i+1 to j<k do
        if arr[i]=arr[j]then
            for m=j to m<k do
                arr[m] = arr[m+1]
            endfor
            k<-- k-1
            j<-- j-1
        endif
    endfor
endfor
return arr
```

here is the psuedo code I used to remove duplicate numbers and print the array but how do I do the reverse?
Ex:
If the array is {1,7,1,0,1,0,4,5} the array after the solve will be {1,0}

Comment: Use a map that contains the count of repetitions of each number. Then create an array of all the elements that have count = 1

Comment: I am not sure posting a code to do the opposite of the asked can be considered a valid attempt....

Comment: is this C pseudo code or any language pseudo code?

Comment: This is for C language

Comment: one approach is double loop, comparing the current value to the remaining values. When you find a dupe, add it to a 3rd array if it doesn't already exist in it.

Comment: Sorry but I need to remove it from the current array. Keeping the value in another array would help me print it but I need to conduct the operation in the current array

Comment: ok, do that then. Is that where you're stuck, how to delete an item from an array? Arrays are fixed size, so you can't actually delete a position. Two ideas, 1) shift everything after it over one to fill in the gap (expensive, which is why you don't normally do this, but this is the only way to preserve the order of elements if that's important). Or 2), write the element at the end into the gap.